# Getting rid of Merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

Merged cells are a PITA in Excel. They prevent doing a lot of actions and make copying columns impossible. So I wrote this little code to change all the merged cells in a given sheet into 'Center across selection'.
I did NOT test against vertically merged cells, but it should not trigger an error (just unmerge them).

```
Sub fixMergedCells(sh As Worksheet)
'replace merged cells by Center Acroos Selection
'high perf version using a hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452164/78522
    Dim c As Range, used As Range
    Dim m As Range, i As Long
    Dim constFla: constFla = Array(xlConstants, xlFormulas)

    Set used = sh.UsedRange
    For i = 0 To 1  '1 run for constants, 1 for formulas
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        Set m = Intersect(used.Cells.SpecialCells(constFla(i)), used.Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not m Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In m.Cells
                If c.MergeCells Then
                    With c.MergeArea
                        'Debug.Print .Address
                        .UnMerge
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub test_fixMergedCells()
    fixMergedCells ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice work.  I am sure that there are a lot of people search for code to get rid of the PITA Merged Cells.  Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Which version of Excel?  I ask because I've just found that in Office 365 I can select a single column that intersects a merged and centered range then copy and paste it to another column and it only pastes the selected column.

Comment: In Excel 2013 for example, if you merge D7:E7, you cannot do `range("d5:d9").clear`

Answer (score 2):

### Vertically Merged Cells

> I did NOT test against vertically merged cells, but it should not trigger an error (just unmerge them).

You code will unmerge the cells and set each cells `.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection`.

### Target Area

Changing the target area from a Worksheet to a Range would make your code more versatile.

> ```
> Sub fixMergedCells(sh As Worksheet)
>
> Sub fixMergedCells(Target As Range)
>     Set Target = Intersect(Target, Target.parent.UsedRange)
> ```

### SpecialCells

SpecialCells are a PITA.  I would use `Range.Find("*", SearchFormat:=True)`.

> ```
>    Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = True
>    Set c = Target.Find("*", SearchFormat:=True)
>    Do Until c is Nothing
> ```

Unfortunately neither SpecialCells or Range.Find are going to find Merged cells if they are blank.  It might be better to search each cell in the range.

### Center Across Selection

Merged cells are not always centered.  You might want to add a condition that if centered then Center Across Selection.

> ```
>  If .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter Then .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
> ```